# how to apply .strip().split() function to an entire column in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, split, strip

**Example of Dataframe**
My Pandas dataframe has a column EvaRange which is captured in the following way.

```
<1000 mm
1000-1200mm
1200-1400mm
>1400mm
```

**Desired Output**
I want to perform some Machine Learning on the dataframe so I need to convert this into a single numerical value.

So far I have managed to do this for a single row in the dataframe but I want to apply it to the entire column.

**Code Example**

```
a = df["EvaRange"][0].strip().split('mm')[0].split('-')
b = (float(a[0])+float(a[1]))/2
b
```

This manages to return an averaged value between the two ranges where 2 numbers are available.

**Request**
Please could someone assist me with generalizing this so that I can apply it to the entire column and accomodate for the "<" and ">" values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [str.extractall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to get all the numbers, then get the mean on the first level:

```
df.EvaRange.str.extractall(r"(\d+)").astype(float).mean(level=0)

         0
0   1000.0
1   1100.0
2   1300.0
3   1400.0
```

Building on your idea of strip and split:

```
(df.EvaRange
 .str.strip("<> mm")
 .str.split("-")
 .explode()
 .astype(float)
 .mean(level=0)
 )

0    1000.0
1    1100.0
2    1300.0
3    1400.0
Name: EvaRange, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend extracting numbers and then averaging them:

```
df["EvaRange"].str.extract(r"(\d+)\D*(\d+)?").astype(float).mean(axis=1)
#0    1000.0
#1    1100.0
#2    1300.0
#3    1400.0
```

Here, the regular expression `r"(\d+)\D*(\d+)?"` asks for one or more digits (a number), optionally followed by some non-digits, optionally followed by some more digits (another number).